# ExceptionHandling in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring with hibernate and when I am trying to insert a data which already exists, it throws DataIntegrityViolationException.
So to handle this exception I have placed a try/catch block in my save method in DAO layer, but it's not getting caught.
After that I placed a try/catch block in save method of service layer also but there also its not getting caught.

I have a testMain method in my service layer and when I am handling there its getting caught there.

Please help how to handle this in my DAO layer

```
public class TestMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringUtil
                .getApplicationContextInstance();
        UserDaoService userDaoService = applicationContext.getBean("userDaoService",
                UserDaoService.class);
        UserDaoImpl userDao = applicationContext.getBean("userDaoImpl",
                UserDaoImpl.class);

        User user = new User();
        user.setActive(true);
        user.setEmail("shariquealam01@gmail.com");
        user.setFirstName("Md");
        user.setMiddleName("Sharique");
        user.setLastName("Alam");
        user.setId(1);
        user.setPassword("123");
        user.setUserName("shariquealam01");
        userDaoService.saveUser(user);
    }
}
```

@Service

```
public class UserDaoService {
    @Autowired
    public UserDao userDao;

    @Transactional
    public void saveUser(User user){
        System.out.println("User Saving");  
        /*user.setActive(true);
        user.setEmail("shariquealam06@gmail.com");
        user.setFirstName("Md");
        user.setMiddleName("Sharique");
        user.setLastName("Alam");
        user.setId(6);
        user.setPassword("123");
        user.setUserName("shariquealam06");*/       
            userDao.saveUser(user) ;        
        /*try{
            System.out.println("Inside Service Try");
            userDao.saveUser(user);
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception Occured "+e);
        }*/
            // deleteUser(3);
    }
}

@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {   
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    public Role getRole(int id){
        Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Role role = (Role) session.get(Role.class, id);
        return role;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveUser(User user)  {
        //  Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        /*role.setRoleId(102);
        role.setRoleName("User");*/     
        //  role.getUsers().add(user);
        /*session.save(user);*/

            //logger.info( "Executing Query to ADD User"); //Since this query is important for the state of application, have info logging

            Role role = getRole(102);
            user.getRoles().add(role);
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.save( user );
            //userId = user.getId();
            //logger.info( "User ADDED to DB with userId as {}", user.getId() );


        //session.save(role);
    }
}

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:592)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:515)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at com.sharique.service.UserDaoService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$956522ab.saveUser(<generated>)
    at com.sharique.main.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:40)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:584)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__USER_DET__F3BEEBFF77DFC722'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.USER_DETAILS'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:314)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:98)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: Post a full stack trace of one of these `DataIntegrityViolationException`.

Comment: Also, please post your excaption handling methods. Try to catch `Exception` first, then log its class, then modify your catch block accordingly.

Comment: Show your try catch statements.

Comment: Here I have given my class and full stack trace... it is getting caught at TestMain class, but not in UserDaoService or in UserDaoImpl

Answer (score 1):

The exception, as the stack trace should show, doesn't happen when you call `persist()` or `save()`. It happens when `flush()` is called, i.e. when the SQL insert statements are actually executed. And `flush()` is called automatically just before the transaction commits.

You could call `flush()` explicitely and catch the exception, but that would be useless, because Hibernate exceptions are irrecoverable. They leave the session in an unusable state. The only safe thing to do when facing such an exception is to rolback the transaction and close the session.

So do the right thing: use autogenerated primary keys and/or check that the data doesn't exist, using a query, before trying to insert it.

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion....
So it means that I can't handle this exception in dao and service layer, right??

Comment: You can, but the only safe thing to do is to rollback, close the session, and throw a runtime exception to signal the callers of the problem. So that doesn't add anything to what you already do: let the original exception bubble.